# Get ALL Raphael IDs on a paper

Tags: raphael

Is there a way in [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getById) to get ALL Raphael Element IDs so I can bulk update?

For example I'd like to do something like:

```
var allIDs = paper.getById(*);
for (var t=0; t<allIDs.length; t++)
{
    paper.getById(allIDs[t]).attr({/* something */});
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This seems an odd approach. Normally you'd give all the elements a class and then update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was simpler than I thought!

```
        paper.forEach(function (el) 
        {
            console.log(el.id);
        });
```